# PHP execute stored procedure to change password

Tags: php, sqlanywhere

How do you call/execute an internal SQL Anywhere database stored procedure in php? I need to allow user to change password in SQL Anywhere database using the sp_password procedure passing old password, new password and user id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to connect to the MySQL database and send the procedure call as query, the same way you would send any other SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you for response.  I am able to connect to database using ODBC_Connect but do not know how to send SQL statement to to call sp_password passing oldpw, newpw, user id.  Can you provide example code?  I am newbie to PHP.

Comment: If I understand correctly this is actually not about PHP but about how to call a stored procedure in an SQL statement in SQL Anywhere...? Maybe [this will help](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/execute-tsql-statement.html) - you need to use the keyword `EXECUTE`.